# How to learn about voice cloning

Tags: neural-networks

I recently discovered AI voice covers on TikTok/YouTube.

I found a programme called so-vits-SVC, which uses your audio samples as training data and does all the magic for you.

As convenient as so-vits-SVC may be, I would like to understand how programmes like that work. I believe the software may use neural networks. Does anyone know what other topics I need to understand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Start with reading the source code and documentation at GitHub:
https://github.com/svc-develop-team/so-vits-svc

For a higher level article read [How To Turn Your Voice Into Any Celebrity’s so-vits-svc 4.0)](https://medium.com/@amaltyagi/how-to-turn-your-voice-into-any-celebritys-so-vits-svc-4-0-e92222a287e2).